# Making links the size of their parent?

Tags: html, css

Yeah, I was wondering if there's a way to make a link the size of it's parent.
See, I'm trying to make my drop-down menu's links stretch across the width of the .menu class they're embedded in. But it's not working even though I have everything else embedded in between as width: 100%;

Can anyone tell me how to make make my drop-down menu's links stretch across the width of the .menu class they're embedded in?
[Here is the link to my site](http://cypri.231days.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the links `display: block;`  You won't need the 100% width then (which will actually make the links too wide, because of the padding).

In general you'll want to be conservative with setting width 100% on elements, as with the standard box model that 100% does not include padding/margin/border on the element, and will often push it outside the bounding box of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `display:block` on your a tags inside the menu.